# Inter-process communication in Android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, webview

I am trying to develop an android app that reads the loaded **HTML contents** in the **webview**(of another background running app).

Getting idea from **chrome remote debugging**, it forwards **tcp** connections in a particular port to **UNIX Domain socket**

> adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:webview_devtools_remote_"process_id"

I tried to communicate with **webview_devtools_remote_pid** socket using **LocalSocket** as

```
    //https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/page#command-enable
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("id", 1);
    jo.put("method", "Page.enable");
    LocalSocket s = new LocalSocket();
    try {
        s.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("webview_devtools_remote_<p_id>"));
        OutputStream oss = s.getOutputStream();
        oss.write(jo.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
        InputStream iss = s.getInputStream();
        Integer i;
        String res = "";
        while((i = iss.read()) != -1) {
            res += i.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
```

but getting **connection resetted by peer** everytime.

**EDIT:** Sometimes getting java.io.IOException: **Broken pipe**

Any ideas about the issue.

Is there someother easier way to accomplish this ?

Comment: just an idea `webview != chrome` ?

Comment: @Budius Yeah true. but [chrome's remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) uses **adb forward** to communicate with the device, from the [code of adb forward](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/ce817c38d208c5a8349504e95c37f1a43f1f3a74/adb/commandline.cpp#L124), **webview_devtools_remote_"pid"** is a _unix domain socket name_. After searching I found [LocalSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html) class allows to create unix domain sockets. So gave it a try.

Comment: @venkatvb did you figure out what was wrong with code above?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you are trying to connect to remote web debugging socket from an application that runs on the same device? This is only possible if your app is running as "root", or as "shell" user, or if it is signed with the same key as the app you are connecting to, see [the code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/browser/android/devtools_auth.cc).

Once you resolve this, you will need to adhere to DevTools remote debugging protocol in order to get to the HTML contents of the page, see [the list of existing remote debugging clients and libraries](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My app is running as "root", but I can't understand how [the list of existing remote debugging clients and libraries](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients) is going to help in my case (An android app that gets HTML content from from an application that runs on the same device.)

Comment: Because after you manage to establish the connection, you then have to talk to the DevTools server using its protocol. Which is the thing all those clients do.

Comment: As far as I have seen, all these clients forwards tcp connections to the **Unix domain socket** then sends the **JSON** dumps. but here I have no clue how to communicate with the connected socket. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, those JSON messages *is* the DevTools protocol. You can look at the commands [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index). Also, you can learn how DevTools uses this protocol by sniffing it (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#sniffing-the protocol).

Comment: "This is only possible if (...) it is signed with the same key as the app you are connecting to"

@MikhailNaganov Does it mean that if I create WebView in my app I will be able to connect to its LocalSocket from the same app? Or WebView's === Chrome's key and connection will be forbidden?

Comment: @MateuszMazurek Yes, that should be possible. When I was saying "app key" that means the signing key of your app, not of the WebView.apk package.